# How to parse binary message to construct AST using flex+bision?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I only have basic knowledge about compiler construction.

I know how to translate source code to AST representation in 2 steps:
step 1. tokenize or lexical analysis
step 2. parse token stream to construct AST

I use flex for step 1 and bison for step 3.

Now I'm wondering whether I can use same method to parse binary message format and construct an AST.

Here is an example of message definition, the memory layout is same of c struct.

```
message M { 
  int type;
  char code[2];
  int64_t timestamp;
  body: A | B | C;
}

message A { 
  int subtype;
  body: A1 | A2 | A3; 
}

// definition omitted here for B and C, both may be a primitive type of fixed-size/variable-size compisition type like M or A.
message B;
message C;
```

I know how to manually write parser to parse a message M if detailed spec is given. But I'm wondering whether I can use
flex+bison to parse such kind of binary message format. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, at least for majority of binary formats you can have pretty much any value in each place. Lex doesn't have anything to work with. Evey definition would look similar to `[\x00-\xFF]{4} { return INT; }` which is not enough to distinguish between different tokens. In theory you could use parser, if you have some custom lexer, but why? Binary format is designed to be easily read by a computer. You don't need a parser, which purpose is to decode human-readable formats.

Comment: What does `body: A | B | C;` mean? This is not C like the rest of the code.

Comment: @thank you very much piotr siupa.  For A|B|C, binary format often has this thing.  for example if type ==1, then body part much be a A struct, if type == 2 then body part is B

Comment: Certainly, but you don't need a parser for that, just lexical analysis. You need a parser when you need a stack, and wire protocols aren't designed that way.